# Dynamically updating KML file based on certain conditions

Tags: kml

I have developed the following network link for dynamic updates :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<NetworkLink>
 <name>Loads TEST.kml</name>
 <Link>
  <href>/home/desktop/farhan/test.kml</href>
 </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

Test.kml file has two placemarks.

My network link file is getting successfully updated on changes in Test.kml file

Now what I want to do is to place an 'IF' condition so that if a certain thing is true then placemark color is 'Green' Else 'Red'.

What should I do here ?? Is there any Java API I need to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how/where you want to host the KML and what those conditions are.

If the styles and conditions are static then you can generate the KML pre-set with those styles as part of the KML. For example, if you want to generate the KML based on some conditions such as population size > 100K => red, size > 50K => blue, otherwise white where each generated Placemark would have the appropriate shared share or inline style.

One popular Java-API to generate KML is the [Java API for KML](https://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/) (or JAK for short).

If the views (based on conditions) are "dynamic" and user-selected then you have a couple of options:

1. Generate different versions/views of the Placemarks based on different conditions with NetworkLinks and [radioFolders](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#listItemType) to load a particular view. The KML could be statically generated once or dynamically via a web-service, servlet, CGI-script, etc.

   For example, the USGS has an earthquake real-time feed with multiple NetworkLinks each with a different view/color/size scheme for the same data (e.g. color by age vs magnitude).
   Check out http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/earthquakes.kml
2. Use the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/) to load, create, and modify KML in context of HTML and JavaScript with Google Earth running as a plugin in your web browser. This requires some JavaScript programming.
3. Use NetworkLinks as shown in your example combined with *[NetworkLinkControl](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklinkcontrol)* elements to globally change the shared styles. See [NetworkLinkControl tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/updates). You can't add NetworkLinkControl elements to your KML directly in Google Earth so you have to author your KML manually or programmatically.

Comment: that information seems to be very useful...highly thanks...let me do it and i will revert you soon...actually im working with a project where i have got list of restaurant and bars and i want to update in such a manner that whenever restaurant get closed , its respective placemark's color get change and vice versa...and all these information of restaurant is in mysqldb..

Comment: If content is updated dynamically then want some kind of refresh interval in the Link (once per day, hourly, etc.). Start with the earthquake feed as a good example of this.

Answer (score 0):

use php , if you are aware of it and generate kml with the help of your table and also you can use various plugins and JAK as told by jason above.

What you can do is :

1. connect your mysql db ( having latnlong ) through jdbc.

2 .Run a loop i.e while loop which will add placemarks as per the latitude and longitude and add other necessary element of kml like :

Element ristyle = doc.createElement("IconStyle"); // this will create an Icon.

1. make a new file through :

Result dest = new StreamResult(new File("file location"));

this will create your new kml file

-- place a condition here which will show your condition like a normal loop.

5 Make a network link and refer your kml file in this for manual updation.

I think this should work